# Multiple PHP Sessions

Tags: php, session

I am to build a PHP application for a website that already has another PHP application running on the same domain/server.
My app will of course be using sessions, and I don't want my sessions to interfere with the existing app.
For example if I want to use $_SESSION['username'], maybe the other app also uses $_SESSION['username'], which could be a problem.
I'm not looking for an extra layer of security, I trust the application I'm sharing the host with. I just want to avoid bugs.

One way would be to do something like $_SESSION['MY_APP_NAME']['username'], but I want to know if there is an easier way.

I see on the PHP documentation that there is a function called 'session_module_name'. The name sounds good, but the docs don't really explain what it is for.

Any advice?

Comment: `session_module_name()` won't help you here: it returns the method used by PHP to track sessions on the server.  Usually this will be `file` (session details stored on disk somewhere) or `memcache` or `mysql` etc.  Unless you have a specific need to alter this, it's unlikely you care about the value.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415962/what-exactly-is-the-php-function-session-module-name-for

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is an easier way: [session_name](http://us.php.net/session_name).

Prior to calling `session_start();` call [`session_name("something");`](http://www.php.net/session_name) (where you change something to whatever you want it to be called).

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that may help you in keeping apps separate is move the session storage to another place either setting `session.save_path` in php.ini to a folder of your choice or calling [`session_save_path()`](http://www.php.net/session_save_path) before session_start().