# multiple php sessions - get variable from other session

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple PHP Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854105/multiple-php-sessions)

hi, i have a website that is managed by two CMSs (same host,same domain). Is there a way to retrieve the $_SESSION variable from CMS1 in CMS2? in short, i am trying to synchronise logins, but already failed in passing the variables :)
cheers, mario

Comment: Have you tried just dumping the session from each? Set the same session name for both _but use namespaces to avoid conflict_ : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

Answer (score 1):

Write to a file and then read the data from the file both different CMS running on different memory and having separate sessions can achieve this through a common database table access or file IO. 
I won't mind adding a value in a Cookie too.