# Multiple Session Instances Codeigniter

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, instance

So I have an app built using Codeigniter and we are experiencing some trouble when a session is loaded and someone loads another URL that would start a session with the same app.

The problem is that the second session is overwriting the initial session (at least partially) and corrupting the data being sent.

We are using database sessions and encryption.

Looking for help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to post some code in order for any help to actually be effective.  Perhaps look at the way your sessions are being started and only initialize your session variables if they are not set.

Comment: Well I need both sessions to be maintained ideally at the same time and separate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a previous thread for you:

[Multiple PHP Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854105/multiple-php-sessions)

Another thing not mentioned in that thread is, if you need multiple sessions for the same data/data placeholders, to prepend the session variables with identifying prefixes, e.g.:

```
$_SESSION['ss1_name'] = "Session 1 Name";

...

$_SESSION['ss2_name'] = "Session 2 Name";
```

Hope this helps!