# What exactly is the PHP function session_module_name for?

Tags: php, session

PHP Session related functions have this one: [session_module_name](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-module-name.php). The documentation only says:

> session_module_name — Get and/or set the current session module

Nothing about what session modules are, what options available, and when it to use.

What is the purpose of this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The session_module_name defines how sessions are stored. You can use this in conjunction with session_set_save_handler to handle sessions manually, such as if you wanted to save/load sessions from a database. A quick search shows that there are at least 3 modules

```
<?php
  session_module_name("files");  // ASCII files
  session_module_name("mm");     // Shared memory
  session_module_name("user");   // Custom session backend
?>
```

Perhaps there are more. It would be nice if the session_module_name docs entry was a bit more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Session modules are otherwise known as "save handlers". Those are the mechanisms used by PHP to store session data.

Besides using `session_module_name()`, you can also configure that through PHP7's new [`session_start()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) argument, or through `php.ini`. The key used in those two cases is `save_handler` and `session.save_handler`, respectively. As said, the default storage is the filesystem.

> Besides the default "files" storage, individual extensions may register their own save_handlers - such as Memcache. Registered handlers can be obtained on a per-installation basis by referring to your `phpinfo()` output. [(manual source)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler)

Custom-made session handlers can be created by using [`session_set_save_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).