# Session modules in PHP

Tags: php, session, module, session-management

I was trying to learn all of Session functions in php , that I faced a function called `session_module_name`.I already knew the usage of this function , but I don't know How many session modules are available ? and when/where we should use each of them?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: php.net has all the necessary documentation. http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly php's function session\_module\_name is for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415962/what-exactly-phps-function-session-module-name-is-for)