# codeigniter logs out another application on same browser

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have setup my localhost in my laptop and trying to learn about codeigniter, 
  i have multiple application running in my localhost for separate purposes,
  but i noticed that when i am currently logged in on one of my application,
  and try to login to another application, it logs out the other applicaton and vice versa.

Any idea why this happens?  Below is the logout function that i use.

```
    function logout()
{
    session_start();
    $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
    session_destroy();
    redirect('/', 'refresh'); 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distinguish between two sessions in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735401/distinguish-between-two-sessions-in-php)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854105/multiple-php-sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to create session for this site

```
http://localhost/site1
```

and

```
http://localhost/site2
```

sessions will be crated for both sites under this url by default.

```
http://localhost/
```

So when you destroy sub domain(site1 or site2) session. it will clear base sessions also.

Check these links @mark-m suggested

[Distinguish between two sessions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735401/distinguish-between-two-sessions-in-php)

[multiple php sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854105/multiple-php-sessions)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

It will unset CI session only, but whole localhost session.

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest solution is to set up a `session_name()` for each application, it will allow them to have separate sessions so they cannot `session_destroy()` each other. `session_name()` must be called before `session_start()`.

On /site1 use:

```
session_name('SESSION_SITE1');
session_start();
```

On /site2 use:

```
session_name('SESSION_SITE2');
session_start();
```