# How do I properly separate environment using sessions?

Tags: php, session

I got a situation here in my software, that can bring me a lot of headaches. I'll try to explain the best I can.

I have 3 environment actually, all 3 environment use the same register, log in and recovery system. But each one of them are properly separated, let say the structure is:

- Admin/
- Store/
- Supplier/

The structure above contains a Register, Log In and Recovery methods in a class but the code is the same. I know it would be made all together and create some identification code to separate them, but the software was not planed to grow like this, and now we got a situation. ;(

I first got the problem when I was logged into Admin account for instance, and try to access the Store/ environment (account) without any session (but of course the session used was the admin account). I got the access and it is not safe if one supplier know about the problem or customers of the Store know about this.

What should I do to prevent this type of problem? Re-Write the code? or are there some workaround that I can write into my session code?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to update your code. How you do that is specific to your situation. There isn't any information here that might allow someone to help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple PHP Sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854105/multiple-php-sessions)

Comment: I suppose it is a place for help each other. Thanks anyway. I do not a coder. If the answer is not here, sure it is in another place. Does not matter dude.! Good Night!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`session_name()`](http://www.php.net/session_name) to define which cookie name is used to store the session ID, this way you can name and separate the different environments under the same Host. Use it before calling `session_start()`.

For instance, every `session_start()` call in the Admin area should preceed with:

```
session_name("ADMINSESSID");
session_start();
```

And you do similar things to Store and Supplier.

Although it works to separate `$_SESSION` environments, I'm not totally sure about the security aspect of it (for instance editing Cookies to use the Supplier session ID as an Admin session ID). Perhaps you should also mark in each `$_SESSION` which environment it belong to.

At login time:

```
// if user authenticated successfully to that environemnt
$_SESSION['environment'] = session_name();
```

Anywhere else in the same site area:

```
if ($_SESSION['environment'] != session_name())
    die('Access violation.');
```

Comment: Sounds to be a good solution for the moment. I also read about session_save_path() function that must be called before session_start() > http://www.php.net/session_save_path . Thanks @Havenard I will study both cases and decide what is a better solution.