# multiple sessions on one web application

Tags: php, session

I know I can use `$oldSession = session_name("mySessName");` to set the name of the session, which I do like so:

```
# FileName: sessionTest.php
$old_name = session_name("TEST");
session_start();
$_SESSION["hi"]="hi";
print_r($_SESSION);
```

I can even have another file: sessionTest1.php which contains the following:

```
# FileName: sessionTest.php
$old_name = session_name("TEST1");
session_start();
$_SESSION["Bar"]="bar";
print_r($_SESSION);
```

I can go back and forth between sessionTest.php and sessionTest1.php and the session will only have the corresponding variable.

The issue I am running into is suppose a different script already has a session started and then calls this file.  What I am seeing is suppose I have:

```
session_name("other");
session_start();
$_SESSION["foo"] = "foo";
require_once "sessionTest.php";
print_r($_SESSION);
```

This is printing `Array( "foo" => "foo", "hi" => "hi" )`.  Is there a way to end the previous session and start my session fresh.  Note: I don't want to destroy the previous session as there may be valuable information in it.

Comment: I think `session_name()` is a function you are looking for.

Comment: I am using session_name above.

Answer (score 2):

what i do is make my SESSION 1 layer deeper then the standard. so i can just use that layer of the array.

some page:

```
 <?php 
       $_SESSION['myApp1']['hi'] = "Hi";
  ?>
```

some other page:

```
 <?php
      $_SESSION['myApp2']['ciao'] = "Ciao";
 ?>
```

so when i want to see session vars on page 2 i just

```
<?php
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($_SESSION['myApp2']);
     echo "</pre>";

 ?>
```

Comment: This is a good solution... it is still vulnerable to each app using the same appname on the bottom layer of the $_SESSION variable which would potentially overwrite data.  I know that session_name allows you to have your own session environment, but it doesn't seem to work if session_start is already called.

Answer (score 0):

use session_name before session_start.

[PHP session_name](https://www.php.net/session_name)

> The session name is reset to the default value stored in session.name at request startup time. Thus, you need to call session_name() for every request (and before session_start() or session_register() are called).

read this SO answer:

[Multiple Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854105/multiple-php-sessions)

Comment: Yes, I know this... I am using session_name before session start, but what if another page is including mine and already starts a session.  so the question becomes how do I end (but not destroy) the previous session so that I can name and start my session.  I have tried session_write_close() without success as well.

Comment: I read that question before posting.  That solution doesn't work if app1 and app2 interact.  It works fine if a session isn't started when this page is loaded.  session_start() seems to do nothing if a session is already started.